# Best general-purpose message format for SOA?

Tags: soa, distributed, distributed-computing, distributed-system

If I have a bunch of servers (eventually groups of servers), each being a different service (SOA), and I want them to be able to:

- Send requests, receive responses via TCP over a high-throughput, low-latency, unmetered network.
- Use a common message format that:

  - Is fast to encode and decode/parse
  - Supports lists and binary strings
  - Won't necessarily require updating all services at once (e.g. adding a field should not prevent the outdated services from reading the message and picking out all of the fields they are expecting)

Which format would you guys recommend? I'm currently looking into encoding messages as BSON, but would like to hear some suggestions.

Thanks :-)

Comment: What languages are we talking about?  Is this .NET?

Comment: Take a look at [msgpack](http://msgpack.org/), [protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) and [thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/). There's a [pretty good article](http://www.igvita.com/2011/08/01/protocol-buffers-avro-thrift-messagepack/) discussing the differences between them.

Comment: @Gray: My back-end code is in Haskell, so it would help if there was a library for it already, but I'm more interested in a general solution as libraries can be written.

Comment: @Radu: msgpack looks excellent and supports Haskell beautifully. If you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Radu's comment for this answer.

- [MessagePack](http://www.msgpack.org)
- [Google's Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)
- [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/)

are all great options. [More info here](http://www.igvita.com/2011/08/01/protocol-buffers-avro-thrift-messagepack/).